# Use Firebase list adapter with Card View

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui, cardview

I have my firebase list adapter as follows

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    mListview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    //the post list shit is happening here

    DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    DatabaseReference postRef = root.child("users").child(user.getUid().toString()).child("posts");

    ListAdapter adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<PostList>(this,PostList.class,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,postRef) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View view, PostList postList, int i) {
            TextView text = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            text.setText(postList.getBody());

        }

    };
    mListview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I have a normal xml with a list view and another xml with its card view

my problem is that i cannot find a way to relate my cardview xml file to my activity, so my list just keep showing up as a normal list,
While initializing the firebase list adapter, I found an                                                               `R.layout_simple_list_item`
im not sure exactly how that works and i have googled, nothing explains definitely why i cant just say `R_layout_my_card_view_xml`instead. Also, please let me know if i am going about this all wrong.

Comment: If you are using CardView I suggest you use FirebaseRecyclerAdapter instead.

Comment: Can you point me to any good tutorial that specifically deals with recycler adapter from firebase location and not some static array

Comment: Install the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter from Here: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android and then there is a full tutorial aswell: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md

Comment: Thank you. seems useful.

Comment: one more question, is it safe to edit R.layouts like simple list items directly

Comment: If you make your own R.layout.simple_list_item, then you can style and edit it like you want. However, i don't think you can directly edit the android.R.layout.simple_list_item layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer to this already, Just in case anyone is going through the same problem, just as Linxy clearly stated, it is better to use `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`, it is a modified version of the `ListAdapter`.

However if you feel like you still want to use a ListAdapter, then:

1. First note that you cannot directly edit `android.R.layout.items`, instead create your own layout, say you have row.xml in your layout files, use `R.layout.row` as your `populateView()` arguments and not `android.R.layout.row`, the latter wont find anything because those layout files are stored in your SDK folder.
2. Please, consider the recycler adapter, its not that hard.